# How to add custom summary tab in the custom azure devops plugin, When Experimental Theme and Multi-stage Pipelines are in switched-on Mode?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-extensions

Currently I'm developing a custom plugin to Azure devops, and met with an issue when I set a scan in the build pipeline, after scan completed, I was not able to see the custom summary tab, in the Azure devops 'Summary' tab section.As the root cause for this, What I found was , I have accidentally switched-on the below features in the Azure devops preview features section.

1. Experimental Themes
2. Multi-stage Pipelines

Further, I was able to see the custom 'summary' section after scan completes, when the above mentioned features are in switched-off mode.

In the development, custom summary section is placed in the,below mentioned placeholder,

```
        ".build-info-tab",
        "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-summary-tab"
```

So, When those preview features in switched-on mode, the placeholder which we are placing the custom summary section, is different than the above mentioned placeholder? If not, how can I implement my custom summary section into, Azure devops summary section when the experimental and multi-stage preview features are in switched-on mode ?

Any suggestion or advice will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How was it going with this case, Was below answer helpful to you?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT No below answer didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your scenario. I have to place my custom section to the build results view as results tab to display it as workaround. Below is the targets:

```
       "id": "build-custom-tab",
        "type": "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-tab",
        "description": "A tab contributing to build results view",
        "targets": [

        "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-view"
    ]
```

You can also report this issue to [Microsoft Dev team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/), Hope they could look into this issue.